# Why this CircleTest Class won't compile

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors

Consider the following two Java classes declared in the same package: Why won't the CircleTest Class compile and what changes can be made to make it work and the reasons for the changes. Please help me, thank you :).

The errors when Compiling are: it says The CircleTest Class must be defined it its own file, circumf is not resolved is not a field, Circle.rad is not visible and PI is not resolved to a variable.

```
public class Circle {
   private double rad;
   static int count;
   public Circle(double radius) {
      this.rad = radius;
      count++;
   }
   double circumf() { return 2 * PI * rad; }
}
public class CircleTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Circle diskA = new Circle(5);
      Circle diskB = new Circle(3);
      Circle diskC = diskA;
      System.out.println("Circum A:" + diskA.circumf);
      System.out.println("Area B:" + PI*diskB.rad*diskB.rad);
   }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have compilation errors - please post them, and explain what it is that you don't understand about them.

Comment: (I can see at least three errors, but I'd expect them to be obvious based on the error messages...)

Comment: there are multiple errors. you are accessing `circumf` like a variable, but it´s a method. `PI` is a non existing variable. `rad` is private but accesed directly.

Comment: Add them to your question, not to the comments. Please.

Comment: @JonSkeet the errors are visible now but I am not sure how to solve the problem for the circumf

Comment: Well, look at the error message. You're using `circumf` as if it were a field. Is it a field? No...

Comment: @KevinEsche thank you so much, so I should change the private to public double rad? What about solving the CircleTest not being in it's own file and the circumf problem?

Comment: Put it in its own file. Circumf issue was addressed in previous comments.

Answer (score 2):

**First problem:**

`rad` is `private` you won't be able to access it from your test class. Read about [access modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Change it to something like:
`public double rad`;

or better yet, leave it private and use a getter method:

```
private double rad;

public double getRad() {
  return rad;
}
```

**Second problem:**

```
System.out.println("Circum A:" + diskA.circumf);
```

You're trying to call a method so this should be:

```
System.out.println("Circum A:" + diskA.circumf());
```

**Third problem:**

Add a `static import` to use `PI`.

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

**Fourth problem:**

As @kevin-esche mentioned:

Since `CircleTest` is `public` it has to be in a file named `CircleTest.java` in order to be able to compile. Or remove the `public` indentifier.

Comment: one thing is missing, since `CircleTest` is public it has to be in a file named `CircleTest.java` in order to be able to compile. Or removing the public indentifier.

Comment: You're right. Missed that one. I'll add it right away. Thanks.

Comment: @Diyarbakir KevinEsche wow, thank you so much guys, it makes sense to me now :).

Comment: @JCole You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thanks.